# asp mvc5 global exception handler return to same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to c# and asp mvc and I can't find a way to handle the exceptions globally, but returning to the same page from were they were generated. Right now in my controllers I have something like this in all the post methods:

```
try
{
    service.Action(object);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch (MyBusinessException e)
{
    ViewData["error"] = (e.InnerException.Message ?? "");
    return View(object);
}
```

The message of the inner exception is a friendly message, like "You cannot create two articles with the same Code" that I want to show to the user in the form of create article rather than send him to an error page

I was trying to reproduce this behavior by creating a base controller that overrides the OnException method, but I don't know how to return to the same page from where I came and show the error message.

**Edit based on response from @JotaBe**

I've created a global OnException filter and registered in the FilterConfig.cs, now I'm able to return to the page from were I came, but the model that I get from the ExceptionContext it's null, therefore I get a NullPointerException when the view it's loaded.

This is my current method:

```
    public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var currentController = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var currentActionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

        LOGGER.ErrorFormat("Action: {0} - Controller: {1} - ExceptionMessage: {2} - InnerException: {3}", 
            currentActionName, 
            currentController, 
            filterContext.Exception.Message, 
            filterContext.Exception.InnerException.Message);

        Exception e = filterContext.Exception;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = currentActionName,   
            ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
            MasterName = Master,                
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
    }
```

How can I obtain the model that was posted?

Comment: Can u provide some more code over here..

Comment: You can also use the `Application_Error` method in global.asax and handle the error.

Comment: What is "the model that was posted"?

Comment: @JotaBe I refer to the object passed in the post, like:

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Article article) { 
        articleService.Create(article); 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

The exception it's raised in the Create method, and I want to go back to the Create view with the form populated with the same info that was sended. Sorry for my english!

Comment: You're trying to make general a particular case. There can be lots of different errors and happen in many different places: a controller's action is just one case, and it can be a get, post, put... Besides errors can happen in other parts of the pipeline: filters, view engine (where the template is rendered)... So you have no warranty that the error happend in a POST and that the data an view were already available. Things don't work like that. Now, try to think of your particular case, and specifically treat it. What's the exact error that you want to handle like that?

Comment: @JotaBe Thanks for your answer, I'm going to keep this filter to show a generic error page and put a try-catch in the controller's methods when I want to go back to the form

Comment: You can make it in a generic way: make a base controller with a virtual method invoked inside the try-catch of your solution. Inherit this base controller, and override the virtual method. So you write the try cath only once, and you DRY.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use filters. A filter is an attribute that can be applied to controllers to modify their behavior. [Here you have the official MSDN docs for MVC filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28vs.98%29.aspx).

In the previous doc you can see that there is a filter named [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), which is the one that you need for your particular case.

A filter can be applied globally (registering it on application start) or decorating each individual controller. For a good explanation and sample, you can read [this blog entry](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc).

Remember that there can be execptions different to those thrown by you. So, you should take into account that possibility to show different information depending on the type of the exception. This filter allows to show different views depending on the exception type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated the original question with an OnException method